# Emails are not sent with Dynamic Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm trying to create a dynamic sender profile. The problem is that whenever dynamic sender profile is chosen emails are not sent. What I have:

1. I created a sender profile "Dynamic Profile" and I have 2 variables as sender name and sender address:

   %%[ ContentBlockbyKey("ID here") ]%% %%=v(@FromName)=%% < for "Sender Name"

   %%[ ContentBlockbyKey("ID here") ]%% %%=v(@FromEmail)=%% < for "Sender Email"
2. I created 2 content blocks, where I grab needed values with lookup function
3. Implemented the content blocks to the email template that I am sending. I also checked the code from above and I got the correct values in the body text.

But whenever I am pushing the "Send" button I got 0 sends in the tracking tab. What could be wrong?

Comment: is the email address from the dynamic block verified in from address management?

Answer (score 0):

When I was building a dynamic sender profile the variables were set a bit differently, like this, but the result should be the same:

Sender information

From Name: %%=ContentBlockbyId("12345")=%% %%=v(@FromName)=%%

From Email: %%=ContentBlockbyId("12345")=%% %%=v(@FromEmail)=%%

I don’t understand why you have two different content blocks to manage a dynamic sender profile. One should be enough.

In the technical code snippet that you are using (in your email), you can use the attribute value function to get values from the field that you have in the source DE used for sending and which helps you to determine the appropriate fromname and fromemail. This field can be used to look up the appropriate DE, where you store the fromname and fromemail associated with that field that you are using to lookup. Also, do not forget to set the default fromname and fromemail in your code snippet in case you don’t have the fields (that you are using to manage the dynamic sender profile) populated.

You would have to share the whole snippet in order to identify a bug.